# Is H a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Is $H = \{a \in S_n \mid a(3) ≥ a(1)\}$ a subgroup of $S_n$?

Attempt: I know that it's false for $n = 1,2.$ Is it true for $n≥3$?

Comment: It does seem to be a subgroup. Closure, inverse, associativity, identity, all these properties are satisfied,

Comment: Is it closed?  In $S_3$ consider the transpositions $(23)$ and $(12)$

Comment: @lulu- You're right. In my mind, I was only thinking of permutations involving both $1$ and $3$

Comment: $H$ contains more than half the elements of $S_n$, so if $H$ were a subgroup, then it would follow that $H=S_n$.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize notes from the comments.  $H$ is never a subgroup of $S_n$.  For $n<3$, $H$ is not defined.  For $n≥3$ we consider the two transpositions $$\sigma=(23)\;\;\&\;\;\tau=(12)$$
Both of these are clearly in $H$.  But the product $\sigma\tau$ takes $1$ to $3$ and $3$ to $2$, hence it is not in $H$.  Thus $H$ is not closed under multiplication.